# SPFX Webpart with React: Can not set own class states

Tags: reactjs, state, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have an app that should fetch some location weather data from an open api. User can input location.

I have 2 files WeatherAppWebPart.ts and WeatherApp.tsx:

The problem I have is, I can't set own state in my WeatherApp.tsx, just use the properties that are passed from above to my class (but not set own state and use them as props inside my class).

E.g. when I use this.state.date, I get error message:

```
Property 'date' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.
```

Why is  this?

WeatherAppWebPart.ts:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField,
  PropertyPaneCheckbox,
  PropertyPaneDropdown,
  PropertyPaneToggle,
  PropertyPaneButton,
  PropertyPaneButtonType
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import getWeatherData from './getWeatherData';

import * as strings from 'WeatherAppWebPartStrings';
import WeatherApp from './components/WeatherApp';
import { IWeatherAppProps } from './components/IWeatherAppProps';

export interface IWeatherAppWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  status: number;
  test: string;
  test1: boolean;
  test2: string;
  test3: boolean;
  weatherData: any;
}

export default class WeatherAppWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart <IWeatherAppWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IWeatherAppProps> = React.createElement(
      WeatherApp,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        status: this.properties.status,
        weatherData: this.properties.weatherData
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: 'Bitte geben Sie den Ort ein:'
                }),
                PropertyPaneButton('weatherButton',  
                 {  
                  text: "Daten anfordern",  
                  buttonType: PropertyPaneButtonType.Normal,  
                  onClick: () => getWeatherData(this.properties.description)
                  .then(data => {
                    console.log("Data:", data);
                    this.properties.status = data.status;
                    this.properties.weatherData = data;
                  })
                 }), 
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Function getWeatherData:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] ='application/json;charset=utf-8';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
const apiKey = 'cf6d62de8a7d61a47748214306d35d4e';
let cityName = '';
let apiEndpoint = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&APPID=${apiKey}`;

export default async function getWeatherData(cityName) {
    apiEndpoint = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&APPID=${apiKey}`;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(apiEndpoint);
        return response;
  } catch (error) {
        return error;
  } finally {
        console.log("Function getWeatherData() executed")
    }
}
```

WeatherApp.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './WeatherApp.module.scss';
import { IWeatherAppProps } from './IWeatherAppProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import getWeatherData from '../getWeatherData';

export default class WeatherApp extends React.Component<IWeatherAppProps, {}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IWeatherAppProps> {
    console.log("This:", this);
    let weatherResponse;
    if (this.props.status === 200) {
      console.log("Status state:", this.props.status);
      // weatherResponse = <div>{this.state.status}</div>
    } else {
      weatherResponse = <div>Noch keine Daten.</div>
    }
    return (
      <div className={ styles.weatherApp }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint Weather App!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Get Weather data from different locations.</p>
              <h2>Es ist {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>

              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>

              <button className={ styles.button } onClick={() => getWeatherData(this.props.description).then(data => {
                console.log("Data Status:", data.status);
                this.setState({status: data.status});
                this.setState({weatherData: data});
              })}>Get Data</button>
              <div id="response">
                {weatherResponse}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to change

`export default class WeatherApp extends React.Component<IWeatherAppProps, {}>`

to

`export default class WeatherApp extends React.Component<IWeatherAppProps, any>` .